# How to convert a PowerPoint presentation to a video file

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

How could I convert a PowerPoint presentation to a video file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [Office 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/office/2010/en/default.aspx) (free), open your document, and navigate to *File > Share > Create a video*. You can export your presentation as a `.wmv` file.

From my experiences, third party solutions are expensive, if not free and watermarked, and the quality is mediocre. Who wants to pay for something they use infrequently, well, for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

That's easily done with **Windows Movie Maker**.

follow this tutorial **[PowerPoint to YouTube with Windows Movie Maker](http://www.absoluteppt.com/movie/ppt-to-youtube-moviemaker/index.html)** and skip step #24 (unless you want to upload the movie to youtube :)

If you prefer the **Original** Windows Movie Maker with ALL FUNCTIONS, you can download a portable version [here](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a direct way...but you could always go around and record your screen while playing the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a program from Wondershare PPT2DVD and it has worked very well.  Price seems to have gone up recently.

[PPT2DVD](http://www.ppt-to-dvd.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Media Convert](http://media-convert.com/) can convert PowerPoint into several video formats.